# Outlook 2010 DocumentItem is not updated aftersave

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have created on DocumentItem in outlook 2010. Let's start with an example so, it gives brief information.

```
objDocItem = objFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Document"); 
objDocItem.Subject = TestFile.txt;
objDocItem.Save();
```

Now, I want to update the DocumentItem name.

```
objDocItem.Subject = ABCD.txt;
objDocItem.Save();
```

But My Outlook Item is not updated in outlook 2010. 
Is there any help from your side ?
Can I refresh the DocumentItem's subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a chance to check the `Subject` property right after setting it and calling the `Save` method?

The fact is that OOM may not reflect changes immediately in the UI. You need to change the view for a short period of time (for example, switch between folders) or select another item programmatically in the view.